# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis (With Examples)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create this table in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    order_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    order_date date NOT NULL,
    total_value varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    order_status varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    payment_type_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    delivery_id int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    store_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    staff_id int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    client_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    sale_type_id int(10) NOT NULL
);
```

I gives me [Err] ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I really don't know why. I already searched a lot, I put this example:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    supplier_id number(10) NOT NULL,
    supplier_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    contact_name varchar2(50)
);
```

And it works! But it's the same as mine, so why does it give this error?

Comment: Because it's not the same as yours. It doesn't include a definition of an `int`  column with a width (which is incorrect), and it also doesn't include the unnecessary `DEFAULT NULL` constraint (it's unnecessary because the automatic default value of a column with no value assigned is NULL, so you don't need to specify it).

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to define the length of int. Remove the (10)

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
order_id int NOT NULL,
order_date date NOT NULL,
total_value varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
order_status varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
payment_type_id int NOT NULL,
delivery_id int DEFAULT NULL,
store_id int NOT NULL,
staff_id int DEFAULT NULL,
client_id int NOT NULL,
sale_type_id int NOT NULL
);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63cdba)**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the (10) from all the ints, or change it all to number(10), like so

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
order_id int NOT NULL,
order_date date NOT NULL,
total_value varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
order_status varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
payment_type_id int NOT NULL,
delivery_id int DEFAULT NULL,
store_id int NOT NULL,
staff_id int DEFAULT NULL,
client_id int NOT NULL,
sale_type_id int NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You still haven't removed the (10) from all the ints. Just copy paste the code section from my answer.